# Css nav styling

Tags: html, css, navigation, stylesheet

So I'm having a problem with my css nav styling. The code works on every other page, just not my first page in my drop down. When I open the page, the nav bar changes to a deep purple instead of my chosen color #E7DDDC.

[Link to the page that isn't working](http://julierostholm.com/projects.html)

Ps. Sorry I'm new at coding and on here as well. Can't seem to find out how to post the code in my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So your problem is the text being purple on the dropdown?

Comment: can we have your css please....you can post it in the description box by giving four space.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default visited link colour has not been specified in your projects_style.css file. To add it you must use,

```
a:visited {
    color: #E7DDDC;
}
```

To disable it, you need to replace,

```
a:link {
    color: #E7DDDC;
    font-family: lateef, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

with the one below,

```
a {
    color: #E7DDDC;
    font-family: lateef, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

To specify different colours for different link states, you need to use

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change in your css,
Add the following styles,

```
#nav ul li a {
   color: #E7DDDC;
}
```

It might solve your issue.